# `Authorization Token has expired` issue AWS-CLI on MacOS Sierra

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, macos-sierra

I'm trying to push a docker image to the AWS ECR repository using the aws-cli.

- I just run the `get-login` command
- execute the output (which returns `login succeeded`)
- then try to push a docker image then I get the
  message:
  `denied: Your Authorization Token has expired. Please run
  'aws ecr get-login' to fetch a new one.`

I don't know whats going wrong,  I'm pushing to the right repo, the time on my mac is correct. 
This was working before, but since I reinstalled my mac and upgraded to macOS Sierra it's not working anymore, so probably related to that.

My `aws --version` output:

`aws-cli/1.11.34 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.3.0 botocore/1.4.91`

The complete output of the commands I run:

```
$ aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1
docker login -u AWS -p AQECAHh....b6Wk -e none https://1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
$ docker login -u AWS -p AQECAHh....b6Wk -e none https://1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
Flag --email has been deprecated, will be removed in 1.13.
Login Succeeded
$ docker push 1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/service-web:latest
The push refers to a repository [1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/service-web]
c1f87971dfa9: Preparing 
2eb644aea3de: Preparing 
9c8843ffe48e: Preparing 
39bb58d049d4: Preparing 
f053bc969599: Preparing 
7169084246b8: Waiting 
bb134a1936fd: Waiting 
184e76848a1c: Waiting 
75c8fcf65748: Waiting 
eb9b9ee1ea58: Waiting 
f4bf35723edd: Waiting 
ddffe1a64b3c: Waiting 
fd1a1154db16: Waiting 
b542e946067a: Waiting 
d49ed2a5e1ed: Waiting 
bb39b980367a: Waiting 
25b8358d062f: Waiting 
997eee521fc7: Waiting 
50b5447183a8: Waiting 
4339b5cb0e1d: Waiting 
3dbd4a53b21b: Waiting 
2bec16216500: Waiting 
b9fd8e264df6: Waiting 
b6ca02dfe5e6: Waiting 
denied: Your Authorization Token has expired. Please run 'aws ecr get-login' to fetch a new one.
```

Comment: This can also happen when your access ID & key has been deleted and you need to generate a fresh one in eg the IAM console.

Comment: [UPDATED] Use `aws ecr get-authorization-token --region us-west-2`

Answer (score 61):

Neither of solutions above worked for my but I found that when I set region in ecr login command it worked.

`aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2`

Comment: This solved it for me too.  I think the reason in my case was that the ECR I was trying to push to was in a different region to what my default was in `~/.aws/config`.

Comment: For me it was `us-west-1` at the end, instead of `us-west-2`, in line with the user credentials i'd submitted to `aws configure`.

Comment: get-login is deprecated. I added an updated answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379808/authorization-token-has-expired-issue-aws-cli-on-macos-sierra/62736623#62736623

Answer (score 57):

You might just be running the command and not pasting the command that is echo'd out from that command back into the terminal. Easy mistake to make. Once you run:

`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1`

It will print out another command to run, you'll need to copy that command and run it in your terminal to authenticate fully.

Or a cool shortcut is to just pipe the echo'd command back into the shell with:
`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1 | sh`

Comment: this works but raises a warning "WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin."

Comment: @Dakota Hipp it's working. Thanks for posting answer.

Answer (score 40):

This answer worked for me using the AWS CLI v2.0.26

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4962#issuecomment-592064025

```
aws --region us-west-2 ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

where us-west-2 is your region and the xxxxxxxxxxxxxx is your account ID found at the beginning of the line below "Repository Name" here: https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ecr/create-repository?region=us-west-2

Answer (score 27):

Latest versions of Docker use a new credentials storage feature which [has a bug](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22910) where doing a `docker login` with a URL that specifies a protocol will result in token expiration errors. This issue will be fixed in Docker 1.13.

For the time being, the workaround is to execute your login commands without specifying the protocol.

So in the command blob returned by `aws ecr get-login`:

```
docker login -u AWS -p AQECAHh....b6Wk -e none https://1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Should be replaced with this:

```
docker login -u AWS -p AQECAHh....b6Wk -e none 1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Omitting the `https://`should make docker work for the time being.

Comment: Removing the scheme didn't work. When I removed it it didn't login at all, it just hangs. I also tried adding http:// instead of https:// but also didn't work, and tried to add :443 instead of the https:// scheme, but no luck.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, with Docker 1.13 on Ubuntu Yakkety. Removing "https://" makes no difference, it says it succeeded but causes the same error when pushing. :(

Comment: This fixed things for me with docker-machine on OS X, client & server version 1.12.6. Thanks!

Comment: Did not work for me using the latest Docker Toolbox. (v1.13.1)

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. In my deployment script I did the following: aws_login=$(aws ecr get-login) aws_login=${aws_login//https:\/\//}

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with elastic beanstalk. When I ssh into the instance and remove 'https://', it works (however elastic beanstalk doesn't persist changes made during an ssh session). Do you know of any method to fix this long-term on beanstalk?

Full details: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=782827

Comment: This worked for me too. Setting the region did not work as told by Kamil.

Answer (score 17):

You need to refresh your authorization token every 12 hours try:

`$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)` - change region according to your configuration

Comment: You do not need to refresh your token every 12 hours

Comment: The token is valid for 12 hours, but you do not need to refresh it manually every 12 hours. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html

Answer (score 14):

Simple Command:

```
password=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1)
echo $password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 787566098823.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: For anyone using the above, you may need to change the `region` mentioned in the above command.

Comment: Worked after updating the numeric value that is in the first part of the URI to match the one that applies for my ECR project `*****.dk.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 9):

Just had the same issue on Linux Mint 18.1 (Ubuntu 16.04) with AWS ECR and latest Docker 17.06.1-ce used via latest [Python Docker client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docker) 2.5.1. Login worked, push failed.

Removal of `~/.docker/config.json` helped. It only contained, probably stale, authorisation token.

I don't think it has something to do with underlying OS. In my case it worked previously and the only change I can recall was upgrade from Ubuntu repo's `docker.io 1.12` to Docker repo's `docker-ce 17.06`.

Comment: That worked. I had a duplicate entry for the same region. which probably caused Docker to confuse.

Comment: This worked like charm- I have docker-1.13.1-162 and this solution did the trick.

Comment: This worked for me.  Docker desktop v.3.2.1

Answer (score 9):

You get also the message "Your Authorization Token has expired" if you have more than one credentials in ~/.aws/credentials (path depending on your os) and forget to add the --p flag.

Use this command to get login:

```
aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1 -p <yourprofilename>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17260115)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated my answer. Hope now it's clear.

Comment: Whilst this gives you a token, the token is only valid for 12 hours. Which is not good for CI. Is there a way to increase the expiry of the token?

Comment: it should be either "-p <profilename>" or "--profile <profilename>" and not --p like you suggest.

Answer (score 6):

I've had luck using eval. For example,

```
$ aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email --profile username_env
```

Didn't work.

```
$ eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email --profile username_env)
```

Did work.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Actually `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email` just returns the command to login as `docker login -u AWS -p <token> <ecr_repo>`. In order to run the command `eval $(...)` is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

The following steps worked for me. First, run

```
aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2
```

You will get an output which returns:

```
docker login -u AWS -p AQECAHh....b6Wk -e none 1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Now, remove "**-e none**" from the above result and run the command again.

You will be able to login successfully.

Now, try pushing your docker image and it will work!

Comment: What's the purpose of removing `-e none`?

Comment: This only works in CLI v1 and is not the preferred way going forward. Better use the `get-login-password` version which is available from 1.17.10. See
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html#cliv2-migration-ecr-get-login

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to post the official migration link as I believe it'll be most up to date if things change:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html#cliv2-migration-ecr-get-login

It states

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
```

should be replaced by

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin MY-REGISTRY-URL
```

This is due to potential password exposure in the CLI. It's worth mentioning you can migrate to the new method from CLI version 1.17.10 for a smooth migration to 2.X

Comment: Should be --no-include-email (2 dashes)

Answer (score 5):

In my case the issue was multiple credentials in ~/.aws/credentails so I used --profile

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2 --profile xxxx
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Profile was my issue too.  after a long weekend, I forgot that I usually set an env variable and didn't realize that I had forgotten to do it again

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the same error, below is the solution I have tried and it is working:
1. Run command:
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ap-southeast-1 (change region as per your repository)
2. you will get output something like:
docker login -u AWS -p xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==  https://youraccountid.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

Remove "https://" and then run the command as
docker login -u AWS -p xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==  youraccountid.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

And it will work and you will be able to push the image.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the above solutions won't be working if you `aws-cli/2.0.0`

For me, I have `aws-cli/2.0.0 Python/3.8.1 Darwin/19.4.0 botocore/2.0.0dev4`

What worked for was to do re-login.
If you are on `aws-cli/2.0.0` then the following might work for you as well.
`aws ecr get-login-password |docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $IMAGE_PATH`

Comment: aws-cli/v2 removed flag `--no-include-email`. In my case, I use ECR's TOKEN for Azure Pipeline CICD, it expires everyday that disturbs my CICD flow. Any idea for this case.

Answer (score 3):

I know the post is related to MacOS Sierra, but for those who have the problem on Windows, I performed the following:

**1)** aws ecr get-login, this command will output a long string

docker login -u AWS -p eyJwYXlsb2FkIjoiUXBnQ2FTV1B6Q1JqZGlH.....*.(Omitted the whole line for better understanding)* -e none https://xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

**2)** Copy and paste the above line *(perhaps -e none won't work, so remove it too)*. The output will show a warning followed by a success:
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin
Login Succeeded

If you need to use a secure way, use the --password-stdin

**3)** Now you can safely push the image
-docker push xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ecfs-test

```
0429f33dd264: Pushed
48accfb13167: Pushed
f3bb6dd29c05: Pushed
e58ae65fa4eb: Pushed
3c6037fae296: Pushed
3efd1f7c01f6: Pushed
73b4683e66e8: Pushed
ee60293db08f: Pushed
9dc188d975fd: Pushed
58bcc73dcf40: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:4354d137733c98a1bc8609d2d2f8e97316373904e size: 2404
```

Maybe this solution will work on Mac too.

Answer (score 3):

This happened when I was trying to push/pull from a registry in another AWS account. I needed to run `get-login` with the `--registry-ids` flag, passing in the ID of the registry I wanted to log into.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue when I tryed to push one of my App docker image to ECR. I was able to solve it by applying the following steps:

1. Generate access keys and secret keys to make programmatic calls to
   AWS from the AWS CL. You can generate access keys and secret keys from Identity and Access Management(IAM). Store those keys for future use.
2. Run `aws configure` in your console utilizing those access keys and
   secret keys also provide the correct region.
3. Run the following command to retrieve an authentication token and
   authenticate your Docker client to your registry.

   ```
   aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin #####.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
   ```
4. Now build and push the docker image to ECR

Answer (score 3):

I did this and it works:

first, run this command:

```
aws configure
```

in order to obtain your

```
Access key ID:
and 
Secret access key:
```

2- `Go to IAM->Users->"your user"->Security credentials-> Create Access Key`

and `chose your region`
then click enter

now run this command again

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin `Your repositoryUri`
```

Comment: I get the error described in the question `Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.` right after this command `aws ecr get-login-password ...` so this doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the stable version of docker for mac `Version 1.12`

I just upgraded to the beta version `Version 1.13.0-rc4-beta34.1 (14853)`
and now it all works as intended.

So if there are people with the same issue, make sure you use docker for mac version 1.13 or higher, if 1.13 isn't released yet, switch to the beta version.

Answer (score 2):

This is the current format I believe, assuming you're trying to get access for Docker:

```
    aws ecr get-login-password \
    --region REGION \
| docker login \
    --username AWS \
    --password-stdin ACCESS_ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the aws ecr get-login command retrieves a token that is valid for a specified registry for 12 hours, and then it prints a docker login command with that authorization token and we are not executing that command that we get back.

We need to execute this printed command to log in to your registry with Docker. In my case , I am using eval to execute the printed command that I get back from the aws ecr get-login like this:

eval $(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1 --profile )

Answer (score 1):

The question mentions that `login` had succeeded but `docker push` had failed.

The two possible reasons for the above condition are:

1. The AWS credentials are expired. Go to the AWS console or use aws-cli to generate a new pair. Store them in the environment or in ~/.aws/credentials file.
2. You might be using the wrong AWS credentials from a different account. Temporarily set AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_REGION with credentials of account where ECR repository exists.

> ECR repositories which are associated with an account works only with those account's credentials

Always make sure which AWS credentials are being used for the operation. 
Check environment variables and `~/.aws/credentials` to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue usually happens when you take a lot of time without accessing your CLI terminal. For this reason when you come back to your CLI, you need to login again.

For your case MacOs/Linux, Please use the following command to establish a fresh login session.

aws ecr get-login-password --region ***`[Your Region]`*** | sudo docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ***`[IAM User Id]`***.dkr.ecr.***`[Your Region]`***.amazonaws.com

Please replace the placeholders with your relevant values.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work as it returns the same error ExpiredTokenException

Answer (score 1):

When performing an unauthenticated pull from an Amazon ECR Public repository, you receive an authentication token expired response. This is likely due to the fact that you've previously requested an authentication token from Amazon ECR Public and that token has expired. When the new Amazon ECR Public image pull is performed, the expired token is used and the error is received.

To resolve this, log your Docker CLI out of the Amazon ECR Public registry and re-attempt your unauthenticated image pull like:

```
docker logout public.ecr.aws
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/public-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

A warning: `aws ecr get-login` does not appear to connect to AWS servers and appears to work even if you have bad AWS access/secret keys or even if you have forgotten to enter your AWS access/secret keys as environmental variables.

It will still happily give you a long password without providing an error. The message, then, you get from AWS is an expiration error instead of a more correct and helpful "authorization incorrect."

*Note: Using aws-cli version 1.11.112.*

Comment: Given the AWS CLI needs to call the [GetAuthorizationToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/APIReference/API_GetAuthorizationToken.html) API action, this doesn't seem to make sense, and I'm unable to reproduce this accordingly, are you? When I deliberately invalidate an access key by changing a character, the AWS CLI 1.16.190 yields the appropriately phrased error message `An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution variant for this particular error is a missing `--registry-ids` argument to the `aws ecr get-login` invocation.

The full `get-login` invocation would be something like:

```
eval "$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email \
  --region us-east-1 \
  --registry-ids 11223344 \
)"
```

Please substitute your own region and registry ID values.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I was using Docker for Windows. The problem appeared to be with the docker configuration. In particular with how the credentials were stored. If you look in ~/.docker/config.json, it might look something like this:

```
{
        "auths": {
                "XXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {}
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.5 (windows)"
        },
        "credsStore": "desktop",
        "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

if you delete `credStore` line and try login in again with

```
docker login -u AWS -p "XXX...the really long password ehre..XXX" https://XXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

, you will should see something like this

```
{
        "auths": {
                "XXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {
                        "auth": "XXX...the really long password ehre..XXX"
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.5 (windows)"
        },
        "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

Annoyingly, I have to do this each time, as docker adds the `credStore` line back in again

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I have multiple profiles. The profile flagged solved it for me:

$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2 --**profile** xxxx)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the bellow script worked for aws version aws-cli/2.0.8

```
    aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

`aws ecr get-login` seems not to be supported anymore.

I had to use `get-login-password` instead:

```
﻿﻿aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <ACCESS_ID>.dkr.ecr.<REGION>.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

For AWS CLI 2.0 use the following

```
 aws ecr get-login-password \
    --region <region> \
| docker login \
    --username AWS \
    --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html